# Div class show after refresh page

Tags: javascript

I have a radio button which has option to show or hide div content defending of radiobutton state, but after i fill the form and I press F5 the previous state stay, but div class is dissapear.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='Chapel']").click(function () {
        var test = $(this).val();
        if (test == 'No') {
            $("div#hideChapel").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("div#hideChapel").show();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Chapel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
 <div class="col-md-9">
<label class="radio-inline">
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Chapel, "Yes", new { @class = "styled", htmlAttributes = new { @checked = "true", @name = "Chapel"} }) Yes
 </label>
<label class="radio-inline">
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Chapel, "No", new { @class = "styled", htmlAttributes = new { @checked = "true" , @name = "Chapel" } })
  No
 </label>
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Chapel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Any comment, where It should be problem ?

Comment: You are checking both inputs, I don't think this is intended?

Comment: You mean: 
 @checked = "true"

Comment: Yes, both of the radio buttons are checked, which can't be according to HTML. Maybe this doesn't fix your issue, but it isn't valid HTML either.

Comment: I changed this part, still have a problem. SO this not change situation

Comment: How do you save the data?

Comment: what do you mean by "save data" ?

Comment: When reloading a page (press F5), the browser requests an new instance of the page again from the server.  Any state options on the page are wiped out, unless the changes in the page have been saved in a server session or local cookie.  If the changes where saved in a server session they can then be calculated on the server and sent back to the browser with the correct values/state.  If saved in a cookie the page will have some logic to look at the cookie and change the values/state as the page is loaded.

Comment: So, it's mean that it's not bug, it's only normall staff. Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After page refresh if you want to show a div then you need to add that code outside click function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Add logic when to show this div
    $("div#hideChapel").show(); // Here you go

    $("input[name$='Chapel']").click(function () {
        var test = $(this).val();
        if (test == 'No') {
            $("div#hideChapel").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("div#hideChapel").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Now, it's save radiobutton state, but however again same problem. After I fresres div class again dissapear

Comment: Thank you @Help  :) I get the point right now :D 
It works :)